# Construct a group isomorphism $\phi : U(20) \to \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Construct a group isomorphism $\phi : G_1 \to G_2$, with $G_1 = U(20)$ and $G_2 = \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_4$.

EDIT: removed mapping because it was not an isomorphism

Comment: Why do you want a formula ?
Is this really an isomorphism ? What about 3*7 ?

Comment: It's not even a homomorphism: $3.7 = 1$ in $U(20)$, but their image $(0; 1) + (0; 2) = (0; 3) \neq (0; 0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$. What I'm trying to show is that $f(3.7) \neq f(3) + f(7)$. Hence it's not a homomorphism.

Comment: Oops, you're right. How could I start to find an isomorphism then?

Comment: What is $U(20)$?

Comment: @David: It's the set of all units in the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{20}; \times)$

Comment: With $U(20)$ I mean the unitary group of degree 20

Comment: Very good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\Bbb Z _2 \oplus\Bbb Z_4$ is generated by two elements, of orders $2$ and $4$.

details:
define
$$
F(1,0)=19, F(0,1)=17
$$
such as $F$ is an homomorphism. This is possible because the orders of
$19$ and $17$ are 2 and 4.

You then get
$$
F(0,2) = 17\times 17 = 9\\
F(0,3) = 17\times 9 = 13\\
F(1,1) = 19\times 17 = 3\\
F(1,2) = 19\times 9 = 11\\
F(1,3) = 19\times 13 = 7
$$ hence $F$ is an isomorphism.

---

This was the naïve approach.

As soon as you found $a$ of order 4 and $b$ of order 2 and $b\neq a^2$,
you know that the subgroup
$\langle a\rangle$ is of order 4 and does not contain $b$.

So the subgroup $\langle a,b\rangle$ has no other choice than being $U(20)$.

Then the morphism has to be onto (without exhaustive check).

Comment: I understand there should be a mapping $\phi(u) = (a,b)$ with $u \in U, a \in \mathbb Z_2, b \in \mathbb Z_4$, but I don't see what the function could be.

Comment: I wrote the complete details.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't 3 also have order 4? and 9 order 2? Why do you take these numbers.

Comment: These are the first I found (see that 19=-1).

Comment: I added another solution.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

$U(20)=\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$ with the group operation multiplication modulo $20$.

Both $U(20)$ and $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_4$ have presentation $\langle a,b\mid a^2=e,b^4=e, ab=ba\rangle$.

To see that this is true for $U(20)$ , check the orders of the elements:  $o(1)=1,o(3)=o(7)=o(13)=o(17)=4$ and $o(9)=o(11)=o(19)=2$.

Thus to get an isomorphism just match up elements of the same order.